# Use of Angular's ng-src in Rails Production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku, coffeescript

I'm building a simple AngularJS app in Rails - when compiled in Heroku / production - the ng-src is linking to the proper path but not producing the standard minified images even when used in conjunction with Rails's <% image_tag %> so i'm just getting a 404 error on the 'ng-src' images only. Below is the simple angular code i'm referencing in Rails (i'm having no issue with the parallel CoffeeScript files). Everything is working in production but the ng-src, which is throwing 404s. Is there a way to combine erb and ng-src to make this work in production? Of course, locally this is not an issue. I've also searched around for this, but have not found a resolution.

```
<div ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
<div class="left" ng-repeat="skill in skills | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
<div class="thumbnail">
   <img ng-src='/assets/logos/{{skill.shortname}}_s.png' alt="{{skill.alt}}" />
   <p>{{skill.description}}</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you hard-code image `src` itself in erb file to check if it is working? And compare it to the value possessed by `ng-src`. Also, can you check with normal `src` attribute depending on the purpose you are serving for your application?

Comment: Updated / added the following in config/environments/production.rb to resolve:
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
config.assets.compile = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in allowing the access to static files, not with RoR or angularJS. According to OP, the solution is to configure in the file `config/environments/production.rb` :

```
config.serve_static_assets = true 
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' 
config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: Correct, I should have flagged mine as an answer rather than comment.